# How do I close IDLE python?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a new learner. Just installed python on my windows pc. Instead of going to the start menu to get to the python command line to select python 64 bit, I typed python in the search field and selected IDLE python 64 bit. When I realized my mistake, I closed using exit(). The system prompted me that it would "kill" the running program and I clicked ok without knowing the implication. I am worried that my action may affect the system performance. Is it serious? How do I correct this? Also, what is the right way to close IDLE python next time? Thanks!

Comment: ["Kill a process"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_(command)#:~:text=In%20Unix%20and%20Unix%2Dlike,to%20do%20with%20process%20killing.) means stop/terminate/end it. Nothing bad happened to your computer, don't worry.

Comment: Oh great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IDLE Python is just the standard python editor.
"Killing" a problem just means that it'll be terminated or in other words stopped.
The "correct" way to close IDLE would just be to close the window like you would any other window when your code has finished running.
There isn't any damage done to your system or anything so you don't have to worry.